# How can convert a string into div.innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the following code:

```
//HTML Page

//onpage load 
<body onload="RenderContent('{{ name }}');"> 

  <div id="cWrite"></div> 
  <form method="POST" action="/save/">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
  </form>
```

Javascript Function:

```
function RenderContent(ctext)
{
  var ntext = ctext;

  ntext = ntext.replace('&alt;','<');
  ntext = ntext.replace('&quot;','\"');
  ntext = ntext.replace('&gt;','>');

  document.getElementById("cWrite").innerHTML = ntext;
}
```

After I post content, the `name` looks like:

```
<span id="newid" style="font-size: 10pt;">
  Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...
</span> 
<span id="newid" style="font-size: 10pt;">
  Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...
</span>
```

But I don't want it as a string in div innerHTML, I want it to be HTML content, the `RenderContent` function is working correctly (it show the above `<span id...` content on alert)

How can I convert it into innerHTML of div?

```
//Updated question

ok...dont call the function...what about this

 <div id="cWrite">{{ name }}</div> //html
```

and the string({{ name }}) passed is

```
<span id="newid" style="font-size: 10pt;">Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...</span>
```

it shows HTMLelements in the string instead of HTML .... below is the source code of HTML file after POST ( the string I got in {{ name }} )

```
<div id="cWrite">&lt;span id=&quot;newid&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 10pt;&quot;&gt;Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...&lt;/span&gt;</div>
```

Comment: Surely if you want to set innerHTML, you should actually set innerHTML, which you don't seem to be doing anywhere.

Comment: chk the question now, that was a typo mistake

Comment: Isn't setting a string with HTML, in the innerHTML of the div, which you say is working, the exact thing you're asking to do?

Comment: this also worked for me...but what about the string like this?

<span id="newid" style="font-size: 10pt;">Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...</span>

RenderContent('{{name}}'), the {{name}} fetch the above mentioned string via POST callback (django python)

so it print the same above string instead of using span as HTML element

Comment: ok...dont call the function...what about this
<div id="cWrite">{{ name }}</div> and the string({{ name }}) passed is 
<span id="newid" style="font-size: 10pt;">Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...</span>

it shows HTMLelements in the string....
see the source code of HTML file after POST
<div id="cWrite">&lt;span id=&quot;newid&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 10pt;&quot;&gt;Write something! To Write,just press the edit button above...&lt;/span&gt;</div>

Comment: Please update your question, code in the comments is unreadable.

Comment: you're replacing `&alt;` not `&lt;`. don't know if that fixes it for you but it's one less mistake

Comment: thanks for the response :)
I have another idea of converting the string into textArea and then get the value of textArea and use it in div ...